# UIView inside UIView, drag to show the content

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, draggable

I have a view and inside it i have another view, the lower view should show the top area of that view, its hard to describe so i will let the following images talks about itself :)

**1-** This is the first case, when the app launches you will see two UIView's, one is added below the other "in my case lower view is the one below".

[image: This is how it should look at the begining]

**2-** lets suppose that i will put the following picture as an image view in the upper view:

[image: The image inside upper view]

**3-** When i put the image from point 2 inside the upper view it should look like this:

[image: The upper view after adding the UIImageView inside it]

**4-** and i when i drag the upper view it should expand over the lower view and start showing the rest of the UIImageView as follows:

[image: upper view after dragging it down]

**5-** and if i drag in to the upper side of the screen it should look as the following:

[image: sliding the upper view up]

So, any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Very confusing explanation among the green, brown and Apple views. And you are also talking about inner view at the start.

Comment: I've changed the inner to lower

Answer (score 0):

Not clear about your question. However, try some dragging and dropping uiview libraries like [Drop and drag UIView](https://github.com/ryanmeisters/UIView-DragDrop)